# Questions about area between curve?

Tags: calculus, integration

1) Find the area between $y=(x+4)^{1/2}$ and $y=(4-x)^{1/2}$ and the X-axis, from $x=-4$ to $x=4$.

2) Find the area between $y=\sin(x)$ and $y=\cos(x)$ from $x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ to  $x=\dfrac{5\pi}{4}$.

I got both questions wrong on my quiz yesterday, and I really want to see the approach and steps to the answers.
Much appreciation if someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)\;$ First question: $$y = (4 + x)^{1/2}, \;\; y = (4 - x)^{1/2}, \;\; y = 0 \;\text{(x-axis)}\;\;-4\leq x \leq 4$$

Graphing always helps. See the picture below, compliments of [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284%20%2b%20x%29%5E%281/2%29=%20%284%20-%20x%29%5E%281/2%29). By setting the equations equal to one another, we can find (and see) that the point of intersection of the first two equations is at $(0, 2)$.

[image: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%20x%20=%20cos%20x]

Note that for $x \in [-4, 0]$, we need the area bounded by  $y = \sqrt{x + 4}$ and $y = 0$. For $x \in [0, 4]$, we want to compute the area bounded by $y = \sqrt{4 - x}\,$ and $\,y = 0.\;$.

So to compute the area bounded by the respective curves and the $x$-axis $\,(y = 0),\;$ we will compute the sum of two integrals:

$$\textrm{AREA }\; = \int_{-4}^0 \sqrt{x + 4} \, dx + \int_0^4 \sqrt{4 - x} \; dx\tag{1}$$

---

$(2)\;$ Second problem: $$y = \sin x,\quad y = \cos x, \quad \frac{\pi}{4} \leq x \leq \frac{5 \pi}4$$

Try to find the points of intersection for your second problem by equating $\sin x = \cos x$. [**Graph the curves**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%20x%20=%20cos%20x) so you can see which function is the *upper bound* of the area to be computed, on the given interval, and which function is the lower bound.

[image: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin+x+%3D+cos+x]

We see $\sin x > \cos x$ over the given interval, and that the $x$-coordinates of the two points of intersection of the curves are precisely the *bounds for integrating*: from $\;\frac{\pi}{4}\;$ to $\;\frac{5 \pi}4.\;$ In the integrand, we subtract $\cos x\,$ (lower bound) from $\,\sin x\,$ (upper bound).

$$\textrm{AREA } \; = \int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}\left( \sin x - \cos x \right)\; dx\tag{2}$$

---

I'll let you take the evaluation of the integrals from here!

---

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 is basically just realizing how two functions look like, then using the symmetry
$$
2\int_{0}^4 \sqrt{4-x}dx=\left. 2\left(\frac{-2}{3} (4-x)^{3/2}\right) \right|_{0}^4= \frac{32}{3}
$$

Case 2 is more of the same as I see.

Answer (score 0):

Check you can prove the following...drawing a sketch may help **a lot**:

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;\;\;A=\int\limits_{-4}^0\sqrt{4+x}\,dx+\int\limits_0^4\sqrt{4-x}\,dx\\{}\\(2)&\;\;\;\;A=\int\limits_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}(\sin x-\cos x)\,dx\end{align*}$$